# Mongoose: find by specific month

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this model on my db:

```
{
    "title" : {
        type: String
    }
    , "date" : {
        type: Date
        , default: Date.now
    }
}
```

A document sample is:

```
{
     "_id": "5aa2d0f9e10fed2054fe1138",
     "title": "Hello World",
     "date": "2018-03-09T03:00:00.000Z"
}
```

And I just want to get all documents which **date** has an specific month, i.e.: 3, which means March. It really doesn't matter of what day/year.

I've found some **aggregations** answers but in all of them I had to create a date with a minimum year to add to **$gte**, but I don't wanna do this.

Is there another way?

MongoDB version: 3.4.7

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of mongodb are you using? your date is of datatype date? Is that right?

Comment: post some sample data

Comment: some aggregations actions works only for newes versions of mongoDB, is important to know the version

Comment: @Ricardo Thanks answering me. I've updated the description with the version, which is 3.4.7,

Comment: @Krishna Thanks answering me. I've updated the description with the version, which is 3.4.7, and the datatype of **date** is Date.

Comment: can you post a single document?

Comment: @Krishna sure, just updated the description

Answer (score 12):

Hope this will solve it. I am also wondering how to use $month in match stage itself. I will consider this as a partial answer.

V3.6

```
db.test.aggregate([
      {$addFields: {  "month" : {$month: '$date'}}},
      {$match: { month: 3}}
    ]);
```

V3.4

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {$project: { title:1, date:1, "month" : {$month: '$date'}}},
  {$match: { month: 3}}
]);
```

Comment: Perfect. I was wondering how I could paginate it with mongoose. I've searched some plugins but none could do both. Today I'm using [mongoose paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate). Do you know how I could do this?

Comment: I am a .NET guy. :(

Comment: @Krishna could you help me [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J-y2p_WksZ2)

Answer (score 0):

your aggregation should look like this one: 
let say you pass the month to the query

```
connection.model("myModel").aggregate([
{
   $facet: {
      monthly: [
                    {
                        $project: {
                            month: { $month: "$date" }

                        }
                    },
                    { $match: { month } },

                ],
   }
}
])
```

you should receive the array of elements filtered on your result

check out the documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/

the aggregation framework is super good, you should check it out

Comment: Thank you @Ricardo, I was wondering how I could paginate it with mongoose. I've searched some plugins but none could do both. Today I'm using [mongoose paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate). Do you know how I could do this?